# Java Spring filtering JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, filter

I'm trying to find best way how to filter JSON according to its values. I have a JSON file and I need to return only subset of data according to used filters.

```
    {"employees":[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"},
        {"firstName":"Jake", "lastName":"Smith"}
    ]}
```

Let's say I want to return only those whose lastName is Smith. Since I get the parameter value in controller there is no easy way how to pass it dao layer and change the getter there.

Of course I could do it by going through array with object and save only those who fit the condition but for big data that would be really inefficient. I bet there is better way of doing this.

@JSONview and filter doesn't seem to help my problem, they can hide and reveal all the fields and I want to do that with values not fields. Is there an easy way of doing this or I need to filter it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Four objects in an array is not big. How big is big in your case? Show us the code you have tried to deal with the data.

Comment: My case has over million objects. Structure is similar.

Comment: One JSON file with M+ objects?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned DAO layer so I guess data comes from the database.

The most efficient filtering would be done by tools provided by database, e.q. if it is SQL you could do `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...` instead of doing `SELECT ... FROM ...` and filtering it manually.

If you cannot filter the data at database level, there is no alternative to filtering it in code. This doesn't have to be slow - do this first and then check if it causes the problems. Avoid premature optimizations.

Filtering is relatively simple operation, that can be heavily parallelized. It also doesn't use a lot of memory, because the filtered copy contains just the references to already existing objects and as soon as the element is processed, it is no longer needed and can be garbage collected.

I had a quick look on `JSONArray` from `org.json:json:20141113` and unfortunately there is no access to the array itself to use Java 8 streams on it. It would be necessary to copy their sources into your project and modify it slightly.

Comment: hi, thanks. Unfortunately I cannot filter is more than I already did. I need to separate loading from DB to returning JSON. I try do to the filtering as you mentioned, thanks.